# Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why I have this error when run the graph api code for facebook in c#?

```
(OAuthException - #100) Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()
```

my graph Api code is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/687925031280154/feed?since=1391244171
```

but the same code return the correct result when I use on: `developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer. Need to have access_token in graph api code. Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/687925031280154/feed?access_token=XXXXX&limit=25&until=1403056007
```